# Crossbar and Pygments

Tags: wamp, pygments, crossbar

We are using crossbar in our product and I saw crossbar requires to have Pygment.  Does anyone know why crossbard needs Pygment for?

To my understanding pygment is the library for highlighting syntax in multiple languages, so why would crossbar need it?

Thank you